# Swift2 cast NSArray to Array

Tags: swift, nsarray

Im trying to put fetched objects into an Array, but I'm lost here... Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have an Entity with an attribute 'date' which is a NSDate type. The other attributes are NSNUmber types. I want to put all 'dates' into an array that I will use for a UIPicker, but I'm unable to cast NSArray to a Swift Array. Please see the code below:

```
var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Diary")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    //Fetching Data


    do {
        self.DataArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [Diary]

    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

    var DATES  = (self.DataArray as NSArray).valueForKey("date") as! NSArray
   print(DATES) // all content is visible

    months = DATES as! [String] // here the app crashes with error in the console - months = ([String]!) nil
```

Comment: Use swift's native map() function on swift's array. Don't cast to NSArray

Comment: Anton, thanks for the quick answer! Can you please give me a hint how it would look like?

Comment: @Deyan unrelated to your question, but i noticed you have your Core Data context in the app delegate. Here is an article from one of the Core Data experts on his idea of how your Core Data stack should be set up (this article is written for obj-c but the points are still good). http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/

Answer (score 0):

> I have an Entity with an attribute 'date' which is a NSDate type

So why are you trying to `as!` it into a `String`. A date is not a string. This should be `[NSDate]`, not `[String]`.

Comment: @ Rob I want to put all dates into a string Array which will be used for populating a UIDatePicker

Comment: UIDatePicker doesn't take an array of dates. It takes a minimum and maximum. If you mean a `UIPickerView`, then you're going to need to format your dates into strings, and that takes an `NSDateFormatter`. You can't just say "these dates are strings."

Comment: @ Rob for the dates in the DatePicker I thought I would use 'dateFromString', but there's another reason I want to put the dates into a Swift Array. I want to display the dates in a chart and I followed this tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/